# BUTTON vs HREF="#" for in-browser application menus

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Searched on this and only found things pertaining to people wanting to halt event prop for default link behavior.

So with all this single page "application-ish" business taking place, I still notice lots of folks using the old href="#" or href="#name_or_id" to ground their dynamic menu navigation.

I understand if only the markup loaded and you had the old #name_or_id AND you laid out your page logically, the fallback of jumping to that named or ID'd bit of content would still be feasible.

Fast-forward to 2013 when people are banging out bazillions of sites/pages/quasi-applications and a lot of the stuff is added to the DOM after load.  Of course, if you had such a bad load-up that only the markup came down, you'd probably not be doing any async stuff anyway, but entertain me.

**Essence of the quandary is:  Should traditional linked HREFs be used for "on-page" navigational items, or would buttons be more appropriate for this usage?**